# Android Drawable Importer not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable-importer

I want to use the `Android Drawable Importer` to generate an image for all devices screen.

I searched the internet and found the plugin is not working for Android Studio 3.6

[image]

so I tried with all version of the android studio from 2.3, after installing the package I am not able to get the `batch Drawable Import` option on `right-click => new`,

I tried the modified package from [here](https://github.com/Vincent-Loi/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin)

But the same story.
[image]

What I am missing?. Or there any other way to generate images?

Answer (score 1):

Might be a stupid question but have you tried "Invalidate Caches/Restart"? Plus `Batch Drawable Import` option will be shown only on right click anywhere on/inside your main module

[image]

Comment: how to do `Invalidate Caches/Restart` ?

Comment: Added screenshot to my answer